# Posting other users comments as an answer

Tags: discussion

A new user posted an [answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/31541/8273) that is an aggregate of another user's comments. The reuse is clearly acknowledged.

But it doesn't sit quite right with me.

I'm looking for a consensus on how such cases should be handled.

Moderator insight appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm somewhat OK with this. One of the problems Bicycles.SE has (and I think a lot of other SE's which are small have) is that questions get answered in comments (or as answers) and the answers don't get accepted (since you can't accept a comment as an answer). This results in them floating to the front page periodically, even though there is an answer.

This should (hopefully) make a few more questions have accepted answers.

It would be better if we did encourage people to write answers rather than just comments though (I do know I sometimes answer a question in comments as do some others).

Comment: I would strongly encourage users to aggregate comments into answers since this Stack has a lot of high-score users who post their answers as comments.

Answer (score 1):

The end result is positive, so I'm strongly in favor of this.

Comments are small, hard to see, not highlighted well, etc. They're probably fine for the person asking the question and the few people trying to help, but they're nearly useless for the hundreds of people that find that question again later.

Answers should be in *answers*. Comments should be used to help improve things. If there's discussion in comments, it's best if the results of that discussion get moved into the question or answers. If the answer is hiding in comments, then it's best if somebody moves that into an answer post.

In this particular case, it would be better if direct quotes linked to the original comments, and that answer would probably read better if it was rewritten into something more "answer" style ("Here are some things to check for").